# Is possible to Perform CRUD operations on google spreadsheet using angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, crud, google-sheets-api

I Want to perform CRUD Operation on Google Spreadsheet using Angular 5 via an angular form

I Have found a link for Node.js where it can perform CRUD operation on the Google spreadsheet. here is the Link
http://voidcanvas.com/node-js-googleapis-v4-spreadsheet/

This is possible with jQuery and Ajax and Googles Apps Script, but I don't want to use jQuery and Ajax

https://www.crazycodersclub.com/appscript/crud-operation-on-google-spread-sheet-using-google-app-script-html-jquery/

My expected result is similar to Google Apps Script, jQuery, and Ajax but by using Angular 2/5

Comment: I have not seen any that do CRUD yet. There is a Google Sheets API you may want to look into. Here is an example Angular App that just does a read of Google sheets JSON. Feel free to use any pieces that may be helpful. The About link has a link to the source. https://mypets.glitch.me/

Comment: Thank You for your time, Mathias. Is possible to at least insert a record in google sheets through the form using angular 5?

Comment: I have not looked into the API yet, sorry. There may be some example code here that may help you. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts

Answer (score 0):

Short answer Yes, it's possible to perform CRUD operations by using any language / platform able to do Google Sheets API / Google Apps Script requests.

Google spreadsheets have sheets and cells referred through rows and columns usually. The Google Sheets API / Google Apps Script could be used to insert rows and columns, to add values to cells among other things.

Usually a simple record is mapped to as a row of values in a sheet where each column represents a field.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts